# Minizinc Array of Sets

Tags: arrays, set, minizinc

Within my Minizinc project, I am trying to generate an array of n sets.
Given an array of t different digits generate n different sets whose
cardinality is/are given in the array m.
For example with: 
t = 10; and n = 4; and m = [3, 2, 2, 3];
I want to generate an array of sets x = [1..3, 4..5, 6..7, 8..10];

But what I get from the code below is 
x = [1..3, 4..5, {6,10}, 7..9];
(I don't want to use solve minimize or other variety of solve as my
purpose is just to generate an intermediate array of sets.)

```
int: n = 4;                 % number of groups
array[1..n] of int: m = [3, 2, 2, 3];  % size of each group
int: t = sum(i in 1..n)(m[i]); % total members

array[1..n] of var set of  1..t: x; % the array of sets
constraint forall(i in 1..n-1)(x[i] >  x[i+1]); % SORT .
constraint forall(i in 1..n)(card(x[i] ) = m[i]); % Size of each set
constraint forall(i in 1..n-1)( x[i] intersect x[i+1] = {}); %
% I can't see a way to keep the digits in order
%constraint array_intersect(x) = {}; % this didn't help

solve satisfy;
output [show(x)];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with without constraints. Here's an approach, though a bit ugly:

```
int: n = 4; % number of sets
array[1..n] of int: s = [3,2,2,3]; % cardinality of the sets
array[1..n] of set of int: x = [ {k | k in sum([s[j]  | j in 1..i-1])+1..sum([s[j]  | j in 1..i]) } | i in 1..n];

solve satisfy;
constraint  true  ; % just used to run the model
output [  "x: \(x)\n"];
```

Comment: Thanks hakank. Yes it will suit better without using constraints. I searched everywhere for an example of nesting set comprehension within an array comprehension. And now here it is! Ugly it may be but (I think) it will have to be accessed just the once as it is simply a different way of presenting the given data. Now I have to work on what to do next. I hope I can call on your help again as all searches lead back to the same "minizinc-tute.pdf" or "minizinc-spec.pdf" over and over again. Regards George

Comment: hakank, I notice that when i=1 the sum([s[j]  | j in 1..i-1])+1 becomes
sum([s[j]  | j in 1..0])+1. I'm surprised to find that this is not an error.

Comment: Sorry It posted before I finished editing. hakank, I notice that when i=1 the "sum([s[j]  | j in 1..i-1])+1" becomes
"sum([s[j]  | j in 1..0])+1". I'm surprised to find that this is not an error. 
I also find that "set of int: Test = 1..0;" passes as does "set of int: Test = 1..-3;"
Both result in an empty set. Is there a reference to this in the documentation? Regards George

Comment: The MiniZinc Specification, Section A.4, states: "Set range. If the first argument is larger than the second (e.g. 1..0), it returns the empty set."

Comment: Trying to generate a 2d array
where rows are groups and columns are group members.
Help with padding out the groups with zeros so they are all the same size.

    int: n = 4; % number of groups
    array[1..n] of int: s = [3,2,2,3]; % nos in groups
    int: t = sum(i in Group)(s[i]); % Total  people
    set of int: People = 1..t; 
    int: maxGroup = max(s); % maximum size of a group
    array[Group, maxGroup] of People: Grid = array2d(1..n, 1..maxGroup) 
    ( [k | k in sum([s[j]  | j in 1..i-1])+1..sum([s[j]  | j in 1..i]) ] | i in 1..n);
    
    solve satisfy;

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question/problem. Is this related to the original question?  Otherwise you should create a new question. (And if you are happy with my original answer, I would appreciate if you accept it.)

Comment: Well hakan, It is the same problem and your suggestion is good.
I am having "index out of bounds" troubles when addressing the extremities of the list.
I had thought that using a 2d array with some zero padding
rather than an array of sets would help but I have shelved that thought
and gone back to the array of sets you constructed.
I'll start another question on the out of bounds.
Regards George